# In Rxjs, can you feed one observable into another?

Tags: rxjs

I have a case where I need to subscribe to an rxjs Observable before it's created.

Right now I'm doing:

```
// Original Creation
function getObservable() {
    var obs = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(0);
    return obs;
}

// Later on
function setObservable(actualObservable) {
    actualObservable
        .subscribe(function(data) {
            obs.next(data);
        })
}
```

Is that performant? It doesn't read well. Is there some way to pipe one observable into an existing one? Or maybe a different approach all together.

Comment: please post the full code including the creation of `actualObservable`; in other words provide a minimal reproducible example of your problem

Comment: Please provide the use case or problem you are trying to solve. Seems like you may still be grappling with the workflow of Reactive programming.

Comment: I've got an angularjs app with a component for infinite scrolling. The component is passed an observable on startup. However, certain services for the component are initialized before the component is, so they ask for the observable before the observable has been set.